# How to disable async mode in graphql with 11.0.0

Tags: asynchronous, graphql, graphql-java

`graphql.servlet.asyncModeEnabled` is removed from `GraphQLServletProperties.java` after 8.0.0 version. How to disable this with 11.0.0?

Comment: I had a look, and could not find anything. You could try to provide your own execution strategy:

    @Bean
    public Map<String, ExecutionStrategy> executionStrategies() {
        Map<String, ExecutionStrategy> executionStrategyMap = new HashMap<>();
        executionStrategyMap.put("queryExecutionStrategy", new NotAsyncCustomExecutionStrategy());
        return executionStrategyMap;
    }

Comment: @AllirionX, Even if I do that GraphQL ExecutionStragegy has a method `public abstract CompletableFuture<ExecutionResult> execute(ExecutionContext executionContext, ExecutionStrategyParameters parameters) throws NonNullableFieldWasNullException;` which I have to override. So I am not sure if this will Synchronous

Comment: You are right. I am not sure there is a solution to disable async. Why do you need to disable it?

Comment: Because I need synchronous requests for my logbook framework

Answer (score 0):

I have raised a bug with graphql and they are introducing the property again with v11.1.0

https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot/discussions/539